# How to update an attribute object's attribute before running acceptance test?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, acceptance-testing, ember-cli-mirage

First, we setup a scenario like so:

```
setupProject(server, []);
  visit('/items');
```

This all works fine. The issue occurs when trying to update attributes of the current user prior to running the test.

Then update the current user with:

```
let user = server.create('user', 'organization', { enableManage: true });
```

This is intended to go to the specific user, go to an attribute object on that user called 'organization', and update an attribute of 'organization' called 'enableManage' to true.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can always access Mirage's ORM via `server.schema` to mutate data in the database, prior to running a test.

```
let user = server.schema.users.find(1);
user.update({ organization: { enableManage: true });
```

That would update the `organization` property of this user record in the db.

If `organization` is an object you might want to do a clone, something like:

```
user.update({ organization: Object.assign(user.organization, { enableManage: true }));
```

By the way, depending on your API it looks like you might want to consider making `organization` a separate model, instead of a POJO that lives in each User's record.